# ActionBarSherlock as a Jar in project

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Does anyone have a solid list of instructions on how to load ActionBarSherlock as a JAR file into a project?

I started with including the whole ABS project as a library project as suggested in the ABS Docs, but my use for the ABS may extend into other projects and it would be handy to just include a compiled jar file.

Step 1:  Have standalone ABS project export a JAR ...
      
Include latest Support API
      
Then compile:
      
Running 'Project -> Build Project' compiles fine
       
 OR   should I use the 'Export -> Java -> as JAR'
           
  This fails with 'Exported with compile warnings ... 
             
and Resource is out of Sync.

Step 2:  Load ABS JAR into project

Add or remove the Support API in project?

How do you load the ABS as a JAR into the project to act as it did previously as a Library project include??

Currently if I load the JAR from the 'Build Project' of ABS, none of my styles/themes recognize the 'Theme.Sherlock' reference.

When I remove the Support API - the Theme issue is still there, however now only the use of FragmentPagerAdapter is an issue.

Any help?  I've seen a lot of posts on adding/removing the support api and ensuring both ABS and Project use same version, but has anyone tried this method as I havn't found good help on simply using ABS as a JAR include.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Does anyone have a solid list of instructions on how to load ActionBarSherlock as a JAR file into a project?

It is not possible. ActionBarSherlock is an Android library project, not a JAR.

> I started with including the whole ABS project as a library project as suggested in the ABS Docs, but my use for the ABS may extend into other projects and it would be handy to just include a compiled jar file.

That is not possible. ActionBarSherlock is an Android library project, not a JAR. You cannot convert an Android library project into a JAR. The new build system under development should allow us to package an entire Android library project as a single file (I think it'll be an `.aar`), but that is still a work in progress.

Comment: ok, that is very good to know and thanks for the clarification on the point about a Library Project not being convertible to a JAR. I'll reset my project to include ABS as a library project and just leave it at that.